# My jQuery is enqueued properly. So why isn't it working?

Tags: theme-development, jquery, javascript

I'm just trying to add a simple bit of Show/Hide jQuery to a child theme.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#openbtn").click(function(){
  $("#openingtimes").toggle(300);
 });
});
```

I've saved the above code in a file called `buttons.js`.

I have then registered and enquequed the script using the following in my `functions.php` file:

```
<?php
 if ( !is_admin() ) {
 wp_register_script('buttons',
   get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/buttons.js',
   array('jquery'),
   '1.0' );

 wp_enqueue_script('buttons');
 }
 ?>
```

In the outputted Source Code, the script seems to have properly loaded.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/italina/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/italina/wp-content/themes/italina-responsive-child/buttons.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

But the button has no effect.

For good measure, here's the HTML it should be affecting:

```
<button id="openbtn">Opening Times</button>
        <div id="openingtimes" class="headboxes">
                <p>
                   Mondays: Closed<br />
                   Tues-Fri: Noon-3pm; 5.30pm-10pm<br />
                   Sat-Sun: Noon-10.30pm<br />
                </p>
        </div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please [search for related questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=jquery+not+working) before posting new questions. This one has been asked, and answered, several times.

Comment: Most similar questions seem to be pointing towards jQuery not loading properly but I know that's not the case on mine as other jQuery powered elements such as slideshows are working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery scripts in WordPress [require no-conflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers).

Instead of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(#somefunction) ...
});
```

Use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

So, in your case:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#openbtn").click(function(){
        $("#openingtimes").toggle(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have changed anything. :(

Comment: If the script is properly enqueued (i.e. is seen with a valid script link in the document source), and the script itself has proper no-conflict wrappers, then the problem is with the jQuery itself, and isn't a **WordPress-specific** issue.

Comment: The code seems to work fine in a jsfiddle away from Wordpress though, which is why I thought it must be wp specific.

Comment: Ah, copied your code over wrong. All understood now, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would also alter your function to:

```
function wpa_87661(){
 wp_enqueue_script('buttons',
   get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/buttons.js',
   array('jquery'),
   '1.0' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpa_87661');
```

so that you [enqueue your script on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook as recommended in the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

And if you have Chrome or Firebug, use the console to check for Javascript errors.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have changed anything either. I wasn't getting anything in the console before but since adding the `$` as per Chip Bennett's suggestion, I am now getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function buttons.js:1`

Comment: That error is pretty much related to Chip's answer regarding no-conflict wrappers.

Comment: Ah, double checked the code I'd coped over from Chip, had missed a bit. Many thanks.